# Null value returned when I'm calling the ID value of my Home page [OWCS] v11.8

Tags: oracle, jsp-tags, wcs, webcenter-sites

I've been trying to retrieve the value of the ID from home page.

I don't know why the value retrieved is null. Im calling it from a CSElement and then testing it from  the "preview" button in the SiteEntry associated with a HTML p tag.

Here is the block of code that is used:

```
<render:lookup varname="Home" key="Home" ttype="CSElement" match=":x"/>
<asset:load name="IDHome" type="Page" field="name" 
value='<%=ics.GetVar("Home")%>'/>
<asset:get name="IDHome" field="id" output="IDHOME"/>



<p><%=ics.GetVar("IDHOME")%></p>
```

I got null, but when I try to get another value like a "Dimension description" it works.

I use the same code lines, and besides it works too in another sites...

I need the id of the page to apply a lang filter

Answer (score 0):

I could think of a couple of reasons :

- Maybe your 'site' value is getting overridden somewhere. Try to explicitly pass the site argument for 'render:lookup' tag.
- Verify that the mapping is shared with the site that you are calling it from.